# update dropdown list in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below AngulayJS markup that loads my dropdown correctly.

```
<md-input-container ng-init="SchoolSavedSearches(39424,2,true)" 
                                    class="md-block" style="margin:0 !important;">
    <md-select ng-model="selectedSavedsearch" placeholder="Select a Saved Search" id="Md-select2">
        <md-option ng-value="s" ng-repeat="s in savedSearchList">{{s.title}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

One of the action on same page is to add another item to the above dropdown list.. Now I have below code which i reckon should update the dropdown list as its bind with the `$scope.savedSearchList` and it gets populated as soon as new row is inserted.

But I am having a problem, On debugging,I can see that `$scope.savedSearchList` contains the newly added row however the dropdown doesn't reflect this unless I refresh the same page.

My understanding of AngularJs is that the dropdown list should update as the function  `$scope.SchoolSavedSearches(39424, 2, true)` update the `$scope.savedSearchList` from which its bind to.

Below is my code:

**Insert new row:**

```
$scope.SaveSearch = function () {
if (localStorage.length > 0) {
    // get empno from localstorage json
    var empData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0)));
    var empno = 0;
    // get all the keys
    var keys = Object.keys(empData);

    for (var idx = 0; idx < keys.length; idx++) {
        // find the desired key here
        if (keys[idx] == 'EmployerDetails') {
            var empDetails = empData[keys[idx]]
            empno = empDetails.EmpNo;
        }
    }
}


//var empno = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0))).EmployerDetails.EmpNo;
var pvarrData = new Array();
pvarrData[0] = empno;
pvarrData[1] = JSON.stringify($localStorage.message);
pvarrData[2] = $scope.SearchName;

TalentPoolService.insertSaveSearch(pvarrData).then(function successCallback(response) {

    if (response.data.status == true) {
        TalentPoolService.sucessNotify("Saved Search have been created successfully.", 5000, 640);

        $scope.SchoolSavedSearches(39424, 2, true).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log($scope.savedSearchList);
        });
    }
    else
        TalentPoolService.errorNotify("Saved Search could not be created.", 5000, 640);


}, function errorCallback(response) {
    TalentPoolService.errorNotify("Saved Search could not be created.", 5000, 640);
});

$("#addsavesearch_popup").modal("hide");
$scope.selected = [];
angular.forEach($scope.Candidatelist, function (val) {
    val.selected = false;
});
}
```

**Other function:**

```
$scope.SchoolSavedSearches = function (id, saveSearchType, excludeDeActive) {

var pvarrData = new Array();
pvarrData[0] = id;
pvarrData[1] = saveSearchType;
pvarrData[2] = excludeDeActive;

TalentPoolService.GetSchoolSavedSearches(id, saveSearchType, excludeDeActive).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.savedSearchList = response.data;

}, function errorCallback(response) {
    TalentPoolService.errorNotify("Saved Search could not be loaded.", 5000, 640);
});
}
```

Comment: From your code `$scope.SchoolSavedSearches(39424, 2, true)` should return promise but it doesn't

Comment: see example: https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/LjBVMW

Comment: But I reckon its does:         $scope.SchoolSavedSearches(39424, 2, true).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log($scope.savedSearchList);
        });    I'm confused!

Comment: So in code you posted it doesn't happen

Comment: Sorry but It is in my code labelled "insert new row:" inside if (response.data.status == true) {